# Do gravitational waves change the period of spinning neutron stars?

Tags: angular-momentum, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars

I imagine that gravitational waves can increase and decrease the diameter of a neutron star as they pass through it.Do they alter the speed at which it spins?

Comment: I would imagine neutron stars are among the astronomical objects least affected by the passage of a gravitational wave.

Answer (score 0):

A gravitational wave can also be thought of as causing a local red/blueshift varying with the frequency of the wave. If you have a gravitational wave with a period much longer the rotational period of the neutron star, you will see the rotation speed up and slow down as the wave passes through the neutron star.

This is (roughly) the physical principle about trying to use pulsars to detect gravitational waves. However, in practice you end up using the analogous effect caused by a gravitational wave passing through the observer and looking at the collective effect on a [pulsar time array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar_timing_array).

Comment: Are the gravitational waves slowing down and speeding up time or slowing down and speeding up the neutron star?

Comment: @DaveTheWave How would you tell the difference?